# Can't do anything after installing Ubuntu on USB

Tags: usb, windows, grubrescue

I'm new to Ubuntu. After I installed Ubuntu on USB, I restarted my laptop and got grub rescue problem (whether the usb is pluged in or not). What I have tried so far is finding the right partition of Ubuntu from grub rescue command with `ls` command.

It lists:

`(hd0) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)`.

Then I check them one by one:

```
`ls (hd0,msdos4)`
`ls (hd0,msdos1)`
`...`
```

But after all checks it returned: `unknown filesystem`

And for `set` it returned:

```
cmdpath=hd0
prefix=(hd0)/boot/grub
root=hd0
```

Also I can't reach to boot menu.(I tryed all <kbd>F</kbd> keys, specially <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>)

I will appreciate any advice of you guys on help me to solve this.

**EDIT**: Now when I turn on my laptop while USB is plugged in, I see a purple page with these cases:

```
Ubuntu
Advance options for Ubuntu
Memory test (memtest 86+)
Memory test (memtest 86+ , serial console 115200)
Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
```

And I choose windows 10 and successfully boot windows but without USB I get grub rescue problem again.

I want to boot windows without usb and I don't like Ubuntu's speed on USB and I want to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu" or from your installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

launch Boot-Repair from either :
the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
Then click the "Recommended repair" button.

After that you'll find both entries (linux, windows) and here you have to options
 1. boot into windows and install Easybcd to fix your boot loader.
 2. boot into ubuntu and install grub-customizer

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

and make your windows first to boot.

i hope that fixes your problem ..